# Remove Spaces inside tripe brackets Handlebars | HTML Language Features in Script Tag | Vs code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, formatting, handlebarshelper

I'm having issues with Handlebar triple brackets formatting when inside a script tag. Attaching a gif for this issue as it's hard to explain in words.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
   window.cyrTabs = {{ {JSONstringify slice} }}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Rehan please add your code here, instead of picture.

Comment: @AliNajafZadeh - Not sure how that's relevant the code is there now. My issue is related to formatting if you read carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for now. Turned this `window.cyrTabs = {{ {JSONstringify slice} }}` into `var cyrTabs = {{{JSONstringify slice}}}`

For some reason, using a var/const/let fixes this issue in VS code.